# URL not found after rewrite

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using this *.htaccess* file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
Options +Indexes 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteRule matches/(.*)-v-(.*) matches/matchevent.php?event=$1%20v%20$2 [R=301,L]
```

This url: `http://www.example.com/sport/league/matches/team1-v-team2`

rewrites to: `http://www.example.com/sport/league/matches/matchevent.php?event=team1%20v%20team2`

However, the browser returns this:

```
Not Found
The requested URL www.example.com/sport/league/matches/team1-v-team2 was not found on this server.
```

The *.htaccess* file is inside the `matches` directory where `matchevent.php` is. I have also tried it in the `league` directory.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I replicated your setup.  There are two problems:

1. I can't get the `%20` in the rewrite URL to work.  I can get the rule to work if I replace `%20` with `+`.  A plus sign should URL decode to a space the same way a `%20` does, so it should be treated the same in your `matchevent.php` script.
2. It was redirecting me to a bad relative path.  If I change the redirect path to start from the root with `/sport/league/matches/`, it works fine.

Here is the rewrite rule that works for me:

```
RewriteRule matches/(.*)-v-(.*) /sport/league/matches/matchevent.php?event=$1+v+$2 [R=301,L]
```

I think you will want to remove the `R=301` from the rewrite rule so that it doesn't do a redirect, but rather shows you the content at the pretty url:

```
RewriteRule matches/(.*)-v-(.*) /sport/league/matches/matchevent.php?event=$1+v+$2 [L]
```

Comment: Alternatively, spaces in the _substitution_ can be backslash escaped `\ `, or even enclose the whole substitution string in double quotes. In the question, _relative paths_ are used in the substitution (although you've changed it to a root-relative path, which also gets around the problem) in which case `RewriteBase` is probably required in order to correct the URL prefix. eg. `RewriteBase /sport/league/`.